# EF6 vs EF core single data model or multiple for "large" database for use with REST service?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am looking at building a web api that provides access to a "large" database of say 150 tables or so and an Entity Framework data model is to be used.  the discussion now with others, is to split up the single web api into multiple web api's, each with its own data model that included only those entities involved.

The problem with this is there are many FK relations that would result in overlap between these models.  So the choice comes down to these:
(a) one api with multiple controllers, using a shared class library where a single ef data model resides.
(b) multiple api's with one or more controllers each, and each api with its own data model.

My preference is for (a).  Why could (b) be any better?

Comment: Why do you think b is realy an option? A project wich contains only one controller does not semanticly mean a *project*. What is the real question you want to ask? This question looks like an xy problem.

Comment: An API serves a purpose. Define purposes and you have defined API's and their required data. Not all APIs should expose all FKs. It's common practice to define API *scopes* rather than distinct APIs. All this is opinion-based though, not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option B sounds like a disaster to me, personally, especially when you consider that any change in the backing db's schema could potentially mean updating dozens of EDM classes. Others more adept with EF may find the difficulty a trivial inconvenience, but in my mind it appears anything but that.

With option A, although there are more controllers to deal with in one place, at least the relational logic is all in one place in the EDM. Also, it seems more sensible in my mind to keep your business logic in a single place.